# Java Program to detect current TV Channel

Tags: java, boolean

I am working on a project that will help determine the current TV Channel. The output of the main must be:

```
The TV has been created and is tuned to channel 5
The TV is now set to channel 9
The TV is now set to channel 5
The TV is now set to channel 12
```

Here is what I have so far: Please help me achieve the correct output. Currently I am getting an output of -99. Thank you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int channels[] = {5,9,12,19,64};

    NotVeryGoodTv tv = new NotVeryGoodTv(channels);
    tv.turnOn();

    System.out.println("The TV has been created and is tuned to channel " + tv.getCurrentChannel());

    tv.channelUp();
    System.out.println("The TV is now set to channel " + tv.getCurrentChannel());

    tv.channelDown();
    System.out.println("The TV is now set to channel " + tv.getCurrentChannel());

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        tv.channelUp();
    }
    System.out.println("The TV is now set to channel " + tv.getCurrentChannel());
    }




private int [] channels;    // The list of available channels
private int currentChannel; // The index into the channels array of the currently selected channel
private boolean on;         // Whether or not the TV is turned on

/**
 * Constructor.
 * The TV is turned off when it is created here. 
 * @param channels The list of available channels that the TV can be tuned to
 */
public NotVeryGoodTv(int[] channels) {
    on = true; 
    currentChannel=5; 



}

/**
 * Get the channel to which the TV is currently tuned
 * @return The channel to which the TV is currently tuned
 */
public int getCurrentChannel() {
    // finish this

    return -99;     
}
/**
 * Set the TV to a specific channel
 * @param channel The channel index in the array of channels. NOT the channel number. 
 */
public void setCurrentChannel(int currentChannel) {
    // finish this
}

/**
 * Tune the TV to the next available channel.
 * If the TV is not turned on, this method will do nothing.
 * If the TV is already tuned to the highest channel, wrap around to the lowest channel.
 */
public void channelUp(){
    // finish this
}

/**
 * Tune the TV to the previous channel
 * If the TV is not turned on, this method will do nothing.
 * If the TV is already tuned to the lowest channel, wrap around to the highest        channel.
 */
public void channelDown(){
    // finish this
}

/**
 * Turn the TV on
 */
public void turnOn() {
    // finish this
}

/**
 * Turn the TV off
 * When it's off, you can't change channels or retrieve the current channel.
 */
public void turnOff() {

}

/**
 * Check the on/off status of the TV
 * @return true is the TV is currently turned on
 */
public boolean isOn() {
    boolean status = false;
    if (isOn())
        return true; 
    return status;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?? and current results?

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be the reason:

```
public int getCurrentChannel() {
    // finish this

    return -99;     
}
```

Good luck on your homework.

(You should at least *try* to implement this, and if you get stuck somewhere ask a specific question about that part, and I guarantee that you **will** get answers here on SO.)

Comment: Yes maybe it could be ;) As well as a constructor that completely ignores its parameter or as an infinite recursive method...

Comment: @qqbenq Not an assignment. I just completed a programming 1 class and the professor is wanting to keep the students challenged throughout the summer break so I am not completing this for a grade which seems a little silly but I want to complete it so that I can learn from it and be a better student in the fall. I have done some research and I have not figured out a way to get the results that I am looking for. I have infinite time to work on this so I will continue to look for beginner tutorials for assistance, just thought I would come here for some guidance. We all have to start somewhere.

Comment: Sorry if I seemed offensive, you are of course right: we all have to start somewhere, and I encourage you to try to solve the problem on your own. And if/when you face a problem - a little bit more specific than 'how to solve this challange' - this community is sure to give you answers. So again: sorry for my sarcastic tone, but it seems that you did not give too much effort, you simply put your assignment here. If you finished a Programming 1 course, then you should be able to fill out at least some parts of the missing code (and also fix the clearly wrong parts). I really wish you good luck.